# Unreal Engine Pawn Possession issues when using Mixed Reality UX Tools Plugin

Tags: game-engine, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, windows-mixed-reality

I am having issues with attempting to start the game and possessing a pawn; But, when I enable the Mixed Reality UX Tools plugin it screws up my Player Controller.

This is my simple scene:

[2 Pawns I have created over a chess board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvl3m.png)

I can easily set up possession when I start up the scene.

Player Controller that works without the plugin:
[This works fine and takes one of the MR Pawns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hldwM.png)

But once I enable it I go from Left to Right on the views:

[Left View: Before plugin and it possess a pawn. Right View: after plugin it creates a new pawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb3aW.png)

I assume this is because the plugin creates a new pawn with interactive elements in it when you start up. But I was wondering if I could override this feature of the plugin.

Comment: Did you add a hand interaction actor per hand to your pawn after you import UXT? You can refer this doc to try to fix it:[Spawning Hand Interaction Actors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/tutorials/unreal-uxt-ch4#spawning-hand-interaction-actors)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the input simulation feature in UXTools: it sets a view target in order to emulate the HMD position, which can interfere with expected camera views from a pawn. We intend to address these issues in the next release to make input simulation work more like a true HMD in the VR preview. In the meantime there are a few things you can try to work around the issue:

- Disable input simulation: *Under Project Settings > Platforms > Windows Mixed Reality* you can disable the feature altogether. This means you have to play on-device in order to test interactions with UXTools.
- Use a camera component on the pawn: That will override the view target defined by input sim and force the camera to be in the pawn location.